# Inequality in the complex space

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone please help me to prove the following inequality:
let $a,b$ be any two complex numbers and $p>1$ we have $\left||a|^{p-1}a-|b|^{p-1} b\right|\leq c\left(|a|^{p-1} +|b|^{p-1}\right)|a-b|$
where $c$ is a constant that depends on $p$.
Thanks

Comment: I edited your question pretty thoroughly: check that the end result matches the question you had in mind.

Comment: i will use this inegality to prove that the solution of schrodinger equation  is unique

Comment: i only wrote $||a|^{p-1}a-|b|^{p-1} b|$<$|a|^p+|b|^p$ and i am blocked there

Comment: proving  the inegality is equivalent to prove that  $|1-t^p e^{i \varphi} | \leq c(1+t^{p-1}) |1-t e^{i \varphi}|$ but i don't know how to prove thatcan someone help

Comment: On a simulation basis, this constant looks to be $p/2$. Interesting !